# purpose of __devexit_p in driver files

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

Can anyone please tell me the purpose of `__devexit_p` part in driver files ?

I find `__devexit_p` is normally using with remove functions in the driver code

**Example 1**:

```
static struct i2c_driver lsm9ds0_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
        .name = LSM9DS0_DEV_NAME,
    },
    .probe = lsm9ds0_probe,
    .remove = __devexit_p(lsm9ds0_remove),
    .id_table = lsm9ds0_id,
};
```

**Example 2:**

```
static struct spi_driver light_driver = {
    .driver = {
        .name = "light",
        .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    },
    .probe = light_probe,
    .remove = __devexit_p(light_remove),
};
```

Is there any difference if I removed `__devexit_p` from above examples?
Will it affect the performance of the driver when `__devexit_p` removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this [LXR listing from 2.6.32](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/init.h?v=2.6.32#L322):

```
/*
Functions marked as __devexit may be discarded at kernel link time,
depending on config options.  Newer versions of binutils detect references 
from retained sections to discarded sections and flag an error.  Pointers to 
__devexit functions must use __devexit_p(function_name), the wrapper will 
insert either the function_name or NULL, depending on the config options.
*/

#if defined(MODULE) || defined(CONFIG_HOTPLUG)
#define __devexit_p(x) x
#else
#define __devexit_p(x) NULL
#endif
```

it seems to be used to conditionally expand it to the given parameter or `NULL` based on the code being compiled as part of a kernel module (`MODULE`) and on the `CONFIG_HOTPLUG` kernel option.

Comment: There are no such macro anymore, I actually don't remember from which version they had been removed. Maybe v3.6?

Comment: Yes. there are no such macros anymore. I just want to confirm if I removed this part from the code does it affect in any manner @AndyShevchenko